# Sending Notifications From One Android Device to Another

Tags: android, push-notification, android-notifications

I am building an android blog app which requires an admin app to control and post and a client app, only to receive posts and notifications.

I have implemented the send notification part in admin app, (without any server code) but the notification only shows up in the admin app not the client app. I want that whenever a post is created, the client receives the notification.

How can I do this?

Comment: have you go through Firebase Push Notification? https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/

Comment: Yes, I have read the documentation. It can only permit device to cloud messaging but not device to device messaging, which is what I am looking for.